# Unable to install module "hrms_dashboard" because an external dependency is not met: Python library not installed: pandas - Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to install **'Open HRMS - HR Dashboard'** in odoo platform.

But I' getting the error below; 
**Unable to install module "hrms_dashboard" because an external dependency is not met: Python library not installed: pandas**

I have already installed the latest version of pandas on my pc but still, I get the same error.

What could I have missed?

Comment: If you have multiple versions of python make sure you have pandas in the version used by Odoo. To avoid this kind of problems I always use a virtual environment to run Odoo with all it's dependencies installed in it.